# mount says already mounted; umount says not mounted

Tags: linux, mount, usb, unmount

My Linux server (Centos 7.5) is in a strange state with USB drives.  When I try to mount a partition on a USB drive to a newly created mount point I get the error

```
mount: /dev/sdd1 is already mounted or /mnt/foo busy.
```

`/mnt/foo` is a newly created mount point, so it should not be busy.  Which implies that `/dev/sdd1` is already mounted.  However, when I try to unmount it I get the error

```
umount: /dev/sdd1: not mounted
```

The system appears to be in some confused state where I can neither mount or unmount a USB drive?

Is there some command I can run to get things right so that I can mount a USB drive?  I don't want to have to reboot the system.  The details are shown below.  Thanks

```
# lsblk
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
...
sdd                 8:48   1  29.8G  0 disk
└─sdd1              8:49   1  29.8G  0 part
# mkdir /mnt/foo
# mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/foo
mount: /dev/sdd1 is already mounted or /mnt/foo busy
# umount /dev/sdd1
umount: /dev/sdd1: not mounted
```

**UPDATE**:  the USB storage subsystem seems to be in a bad state.  When the USB drive is removed, the 'lsusb' output still shows the device.  And when other USB drives are inserted, they don't show up at all.  I tried to unload and reload the 'usb-storage' kernel module, but because it is in use it won't unload it.

I think this could be a firmware or hardware issue.

Comment: The output of `cat /proc/mounts` would be useful to include in your question.

Comment: Same problem here in a different context with /dev/sr0. Output of /proc/mounts shows: not mounted.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a new mount point instead of /mnt/Foo says "mounted OR busy"

May want to try with Sudo as well

Comment: I do create a new mount point each time, as the session transcript indicates.  I am running the commands as root, so no need for sudo.

Comment: You are right about not needing sudo; but yes it is advised to create a unique mount point for each path especially if a process is still holding the path

Comment: The only time the `or busy` should show up is when the device is an LVM (or maybe a md) volume. It's perfectly possible to mount a new file system on `/mnt/foo` when a process has `/mnt/foo` open or if another device is already mounted there. Is `/dev/sdd1` being scanned by fsck or an anti-virus at the time of the mount command?